# SQL Server pattern match without RegEx

Tags: sql-server-2005, pattern-matching

I am trying to search all instances of an expression used in stored procedures and have this:

```
SELECT name, type_desc, create_date, modify_date
    FROM sys.procedures 
    WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) LIKE '%ufn_TurnFlagOn(5,ColumnA)%'
ORDER BY name
```

But this will not return the sps that may have a space between the function parameters like:

```
ufn_TurnFlagOn( 5,ColumnA )
ufn_TurnFlagOn(5, ColumnA)
ufn_TurnFlagOn( 5,ColumnA)
```

Please note:

- I cannot use the "_" wildcard like this `LIKE
  '%ufn_TurnFlagOn(_5_,_ColumnA_)%'` because it matches exactly a
  single character, hence it will not match
  `ufn_TurnFlagOn(5,ColumnA)` and some more.
- I do not have CLR Integration (nor can I register it now) hence I
  cannot use regexes.

Alternative is to run the query multiple times with all possibilities, but is there a better way to accomplish this in 1 query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If spaces are the only problem, you could just use `REPLACE` to remove them, and then have:

```
WHERE REPLACE(OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id), ' ', '') 
    LIKE '%ufn_TurnFlagOn(5,ColumnA)%'
```

Comment: +1, this is good, wouldn't be hard to expand to cover tabs etc. as well.

Comment: +1. Why didn't I think of this before? Thank you. (Will wait a bit more for other alternatives before I accept this as best answer)